# View local website on a network using a proxy server along with iPad

Tags: apache, ipad, proxy, xampp, fiddler

I have a local wordpress website which runs over an Apache server using XAMPP application. Now I would like to test my website with my iPad before going live. The following is the current network configuration (server/client) and XAMPP installation details:

- server PC IP: 192.168.0.1
- iPad IP: 192.168.0.3
- iPad subnet mask: 255.255.255.0
- XAMPP Control Panel: 3.2.2
- PHP: 5.6.14
- Apache: 2.4.23
- phpMyAdmin: 5.4.1

I created a virtual host in the **httpd-vhosts.conf** file:

```
##default Localhost settings
<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/"
   ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/{folder_name}/"
   ServerName notebook.{folder_name}.local
</VirtualHost>`
```

To get the website running on a private network, I have also setup the **hosts** file accordingly:

```
192.168.0.1 notebook.{folder_name}.local
```

Finally, the **httpd.conf** file has been modified as well to accept all specified clients on the network:

```
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs">
  # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
  # or any combination of:
  #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
  #
  # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
  # doesn't give it to you.
  #
  # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
  # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
  # for more information.
  #
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
  #
  # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
  # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
  #   AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
  #
     AllowOverride All
  #
  # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
  #
     Require local
     Require ip 127.0.0.1
     Require ip 192.168.0.1
     Require ip 192.168.0.2
     Require ip 192.168.0.3
 </Directory>
```

I then installed Fiddler 4 on the server PC to get it acting as a proxy server and setup as follows:

A. Telerik Fiddler Options > Connections:

- Allow remote computers to connect: checked
- Fiddler listen on port: 8888

B. File > Capture Traffic: ON

Finally, on my iPad Wi-Fi network settings, for the private network I am intended to use, I setup the Proxy HTTP as follows:

- Type: MANUAL
- Server: 192.168.0.1
- Port: 8888

Now, my server pc and all clients other than iPad (other computers I have on network), can view and navigate the website using the servername I had setup (notebook.{folder_name}.local), my iPad will not work instead.

If I go for the server pc IP (192.168.0.1) I can view the XAMPP dashboard and I can also get access to the phpMyAdmin database. If I go for the servername (notebook.{folder_name}.local) I get nothing.

Thank you in advance for your help.
Bye.

*Riccardo*

Comment: Is Fiddler really running on 192.168.0.1? What do you see with no proxy set on the IPad if you navigate to `192.168.0.1:8888` on the iPad?

Comment: @EricLaw Hello Eric. I get a page that states "Fiddler echo service... This page returned a HTTP/200 response". Yes, Fiddler is running on the server PC. I can view the xmapp dashboard, I can get full access to the phpMyAdmin  database (only by digit 192.168.0.1) but no chance to view my website on the iPad, neither by digit the address 192.168.0.1 nor by digit the server name. Thank you for your help.

Comment: What does "digit the server name" mean? If you navigate to other sites with standard hostnames (e.g. example.com) on the iPad with the proxy configured, does Fiddler capture the traffic properly? If so, then the iPad is probably bypassing the proxy for *.local, which is easily worked around by having Fiddler rewrite the inbound URLs from the iPad.

Comment: The servername which I had setup in the vhosts.conf file (notebook.xxx.local). I cannot understand what are you referring to about the last part of your message ("... Which is easily worked around..."). Thank you.

Comment: In Fiddler, choose Tools > Hosts and add a line  `notebook.xxx.local    notebook.fiddler`. On the ipad, visit `notebook.fiddler`. Fiddler gets the request for the fake hostname and converts it into the other hostname before passing it along.

Comment: It does not work, at all. I have just tried all kind of combinations. It won't work. Sorry.

Comment: "It does not work" doesn't explain what happens. You should consider clicking Help > Fiddler Discussions and discussing what does happen in the community.